# Java Sanitize Input for Database without PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I know I've read the easy way of sanitizing user input into a database with Java is using PreparedStatement. But I was wondering if there was another way to sanitize user input or sanitize input and then get the return value of the input that was sanitized with PreparedStatements?

Comment: Yes I mean sanitize as in escape characters

Comment: Technically, the statement "the easy way of sanitizing user input into a database with Java is using PreparedStatement" is incorrect. A prepared statement doesn't sanitize: parameter values bypass the SQL parser. The correct statement is "the easy way to _avoid having to sanitize_ user input is using PreparedStatement"

Answer (score 5):

`PreparedStatement` doesn't sanitize anything.  That's what binding and validating prior to getting to your persistence tier is for.  You should be doing that regardless.

Why the objection to `PreparedStatement`?  That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I think he's referring to the fact that `PreparedStatement` will automatically escape special characters to prevent SQL injection attacks and the like, if you use the `setXXX()` methods to set parameters in the SQL string.

Comment: Yes, I know what PreparedStatement is.  Automatically escaping is one thing; binding and validating is another.

Comment: Internally, PreparedStatement doesn't escape special characters in parameter values (for most databases) - parameter values bypass the SQL parser. That's faster than first escaping and then parsing them.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to _avoid_ PreparedStatement: it's dangerous (escaping correctly is tricky) and it's slower than using a prepared statement.

Answer (score -1):

If by Sanitize you mean "replacing special character by encoded characters", you can probably try"URLEncoder".

However this is used for creating encoded parameters in a particular Mime format.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

See examples here

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/URLEncodeTest.htm

Comment: This is for URLs, not for databases (SQL).